# Error java:63: reached end of file while parsing

Tags: java, parsing

I get this error when parsing:

```
error java:63: reached end of file while parsing
```

What can I do?

```
//Get ListView object from xml
listView=(listView)findViewById(R.id.list)

//ListView item Click Listener
listView.setOnClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener(){
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
      int position, long id) {

        // ListView Clicked item index
        int itemPosition     = position;

        // ListView Clicked item value
        String  itemValue    = (String) listView.getItemAtPosition(position);
}
```

Comment: Above `onItemClick` misses a `}`.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a closing } at the end of your source code file.